# Positioning two buttons away from one another in a tablelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to position two buttons away from one another in a TableRow.. but I cant do it.

**Update**

```
     <TableRow
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="20dip"
     android:paddingTop="20dip" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/contintue"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:text="Finish Test" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/contintue"
         android:text="Add Question" />

 </TableRow>
```

They both sit in teh left side of the table row.. I tried to shift them with Gravity right and left...but it doesnt produce an effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `layout_gravity` instead of `gravity` to right and left on each button.

**Update:**

You also have to make sure that your columns are the right size in the first place. Use this attribute on your table:

```
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

You may not actually need the `layout_gravity` depending on how you want everything to look.

Comment: see update... no effect..may be I should put hte whole thing in relative view

Comment: Thats true... i gave it a value of 1 and it worked.. Why cant I put a relative layout inside a tableRow??..it shows me an error

Comment: `RelativeLayout` should work just fine inside a tableRow. The entire `RelativeLayout` will be contained within a single table cell however.